# Can a SharePoint Feature be part of multiple Solution Packages?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, solution-package, features

We have an existing Branding Solution Package (WSP) that contains multiple features  for page layouts, list definitions, master pages etc..

Because of the number of files/features (dozens if not hundreds) I would like to create a separate solution package that only contains the Page Layouts Feature. Is this possible? (and advisable?)

We are on SharePoint 2013 (On-Prem)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can split up your Features and then declare the Feature dependencies. Once this is done you wont be able to activate a Feature if the Feature(s) it depends on have not been activated.

[How to: Add and Remove Feature Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231535(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Just to clarify I have Package1 which contains Features Feature1, Feature2, Feature3. I want to create Package2 which only contains Feature1 (same GUID). I'm wondering if I can deploy Package2 without removing Package1

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realize that your question related to deployment. Do you want to have Feature1 in both Package1 and Package2?

Comment: That is correct, I would like to have the same feature in both packages

Comment: I think you could do it but you're going to have to fight hard against the Visual Studio tooling to make it work. If I was going to attempt this I would centralize all the code into a DLL and also have only one copy of any files used by the elements in the Feature and then link to those files in my Visual Studio project.

Comment: As an alternative I would advise that you split out Feature1 into a single Package and then declare Feature dependencies as appropriate in the original Package

Answer (score 0):

I just had time to look at this again. The answer is yes, a feature can be part of multiple solution packages. I just created a new project and edited the package manifest with Package editor per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10828713)